# django ordering results are changed when i update one record

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I used postgresql and rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter library

in my viewset:

```
...

serializer_class = myModelSerializer

querset = myModel.objects.all().order_by('-id')

filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter)

ordering_fields = ('fields1', 'fields2')
```

for example: i have five record ordering by fields2 desc:

- record3
- record2
- record1
- record4
- record5

when I update record2 fields3 and still ordering by fields desc, the ordering results got changed:

- record2
- record1
- record3
- record4
- record5

Why is this happening?

by the way: This problem was not happend on mysql

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem

```
filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, MyOrderingFilter)
```

just append default sort field ("id" or "create_time") in ordering_list

```
from rest_framework.filters import OrderdingFilter
class MyOrderingFilter(OrderingFilter):
    def get_orderding(self, request, queryset, view):
        orderding = super().get_orderding(request, queryset, view)
        if ordering and orderding != self.get_default_orderding(view):
            orderding.append(self.get_default_orderding(view)[0])
        return orderding
```